# JQuery Dialog Scrollbar Position

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i set the scrollbar in my dialog to be set to bottom by default, so that when the dialog opens, the scrollbar is at the bottom

```
         $( "#report-dialog" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "blind",
            hide: "fold",
            width: 850,
            height: 600,

            buttons: {
                Close: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#element').dialog({
    open: function(){
        var el = $(this);
        var scrollY = this.scrollHeight;

        el.scrollTop(scrollY);
        el.parent().queue(function(next){
            el.scrollTop(scrollY);
            next();
        });
    }
});
```

The first scrollTop sets the scroll when the dialog opens, but apparently jQueryUI resets the scroll when the animation is finished, so we add another function to the element's parent queue(the one doing the animation), so it can reset the height again after the animation is finished.

Comment: but there is a problem now,
buttons: {
                Close: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
is not working

Comment: I see, my bad, I forgot to continue the queue, will edit the comment with the corrected source.

Comment: well Draivin, actually am new to these web applications and stuff, can you tell me what would be better to learn jquery and concepts , any book or blog or something else you can suggest, and if you can suggest for ajax too

Comment: Sorry, can't really help you there since I'm not really a proficient guy with jQuery, I'm quite experienced with vanilla JS, so I can solve my way around problems like yours, but that's it.